# Foundry not outputting console.log

Tags: solidity, foundry

Followed docs at https://book.getfoundry.sh/reference/forge-std/console-log

Tests are passing but console.log is not doing anything. I excepted it would print the output in the terminal.

Test contract is as follows:

```
pragma solidity =0.8.17;
import "forge-std/console.sol";
import "forge-std/Test.sol";

contract ProjectTest is Test {
  ProjectRouter router;

  function setUp() public {
    router = new ProjectRouter();
    console.log("DONE"); // NOT WORKING
  }

  function test() public { // PASSED
    string memory name = router.name();
    assertEq(router.name(), "Router");
  }

  function test123() public { // PASSED
    console.log(123); // NOT WORKING
  }
}
```

Tried

```
contract ProjectTest is console, Test
```

But that gave more than 256 errors which look like this:

```
error[9097]: DeclarationError: Identifier already declared.
    --> lib/forge-std/src/console.sol:2090:3:
     |
2090 |   function log(bool p0, bool p1, bool p2, uint p3) internal view {
     |   ^ (Relevant source part starts here and spans across multiple lines).
Note: The previous declaration is here:
  --> lib/forge-std/lib/ds-test/src/test.sol:19:5:
   |
19 |     event log                    (string);
   |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Comment: what command are you running for the test?

Comment: I'm using "forge test"

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You need to increase the verbosity of `forge test`

That is, try `forge test -vv` for the log output.  or `forge test -vvvv` for a full trace of every function call.

https://book.getfoundry.sh/reference/forge/forge-test

> -v
> --verbosity
> Verbosity of the EVM.
>
> ```
> Pass multiple times to increase the verbosity (e.g. -v, -vv, -vvv).
>
> Verbosity levels:
> - 2: Print logs for all tests
> - 3: Print execution traces for failing tests
> - 4: Print execution traces for all tests, and setup traces for failing tests
> - 5: Print execution and setup traces for all tests
> ```